# Having trouble ints from a program reading file

Tags: c, string, file, int, scanf

Im working on a self-project where im trying to learn how to write and create files. Theres two problems. The first program should be writing information into a file, while the integers the user gives does copy into the file, the file is also giving illegible characters in the txt file its creating. The second issue is that when I compile program #2 it does not display the information entered from the txt file. (Sidenote: The libs I used were string, stdlib, stdio) This program is written in C

Program #1:

```
int main(void)
{
FILE *fp;
int pnum, quantity;
float price;
char num1[20];
char num2[20];
char num3[20];
char str[100] = "";
str[0] = '\0';

printf("This program stores a business inventory.\n");
fp = fopen( "inventory.txt" , "w" );

do
{
printf("Please enter item data (part number, quanitity, price): ");
scanf("%d, %d, %f", &pnum, &quantity, &price);

sprintf(num1, "%d", pnum);
sprintf(num2, "%d", quantity);
sprintf(num3, "%.1f", price);

strcat(str, num1);
strcat(str, " ");
if(pnum != 0)
{
    strcat(str, num2);
    strcat(str, " ");
    strcat(str, num3);
    strcat(str, " ");
}
else
{
strcat(str, num1);
strcat(str, " ");
strcat(str, num1);
strcat(str, " ");
strcat(str, num1);
strcat(str, " ");
}


}while( (pnum != 0));


fwrite(str , 1 , sizeof(str)+ 1 , fp);
fclose(fp);
printf("Thank you. Inventory stored in file inventory.txt.\n");

return 0;
}
```

Program #2:

```
int main(void)
{
FILE * fp;
int pnum, quantity;
float price;

printf("Below are the items in your inventory\n");

printf("Part# Quantity Item Price\n");



fp = fopen("inventory.txt", "r");
rewind(fp);
do
{
fscanf(fp, "%d %d %f", &pnum, &quantity, &price);

printf("%5d", pnum);
printf("%9d", quantity);
printf("       $%.1f\n", price);

}while(pnum != 0);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to find a tool that dumps the bytes of the file in a readable format, such as `xxd` or `od -c` or other similar programs.  Apply that to your file.  I believe you'll find you have null bytes in the file, which are going to mess up the reading process.  You're using too many `strcat()` operations; you should use `sprintf()` to create the whole string in one call.  You must check the value returned from `fscanf()` in the reading code — it may read the first lot of data; it probably won't read any more because of the null bytes.

Comment: Is it possible to get an example on how to use sprintf() with the 3 given integers in order to create the whole string in one call? Also, the user can input pnum, quantity, price multiple times. will sprintf() add on to that string?

Comment: `snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%d %d %f\n", pnum, quantity, price);` would do.  I misread the code in part (the null byte problem isn't there in the form I thought) — but you have some undefined behaviour.  You need to put a null byte at the start of the string before you do an `strcat()` operations — otherwise, you don't know where you are going to start copying data.  You shouldn't write more bytes than there are in `str`.  And you should check against string overflow.  You need to check the input `scanf()` too.  All inputs need to be checked.

Comment: Note that `snprintf()` returns how many characters it wrote, or would have written, into the string.  You can use that to do concatenation.

Comment: How would one put a null byte at the beginning of the string? Would this fix the undefined behavior in the txt file? Also, just to clarify. should the snprintf function replace the strcats I written into the program?

Comment: `str[0] = '\0';` or `char str[100] = "";` or …  Fixing that cleans up much of the UB.  You don't check for buffer overflow.  Do you have to use `fwrite()` to write the data?  It would be even more natural to use `fprintf()` (without any need for `snprintf()`) to write the data since you're using `fscanf()` to read it.  Use `fwrite()` to write when you'll use `fread()` to read the data.  Use `fprintf()` to write when you'll use `fscanf()` to read the data.  They work in pairs!

Comment: Adding these to the program fixed the undefined characters at the beginning of the txt file but they are still there after the user input. Anyway to fix this? User inputs : 10, 3, 10.5, 3, 5, 2.5, 0 File example example : 10 3 10.5 3 5 2.5 0 0 0 \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00

Comment: And yes, the project requires I use fwrite().

Comment: Those are there because you `fwrite()` the number of bytes in `str` (plus 1 in the original code), not just the number of bytes in the string.  They're ignorable.  The stray comma will wreck the input too; you need `10, 3, 10.5` then `3, 5, 2.5` with no comma (but space or newline) between the two sequences.  Are you sure you aren't required to use `fread()` too if you're required to use `fwrite()`?  And is the data in the file supposed to be binary or text?

Comment: The only constraint is that the program must be written using fwrite().  The stray comma was an accident, the real user input does not have that.

Comment: The code works actually! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

One of the key problems is that you don't make sure `str` is an empty string before you start, so you don't know what garbage is at the beginning of the output.  Another is that you write the whole of `str` plus a byte that isn't part of `str` to the file, when you really only need to write the formatted data.  Since `fwrite()` is required by the exercise, the code can continue to use that.

You should check inputs; you should check that files open; you should avoid buffer overflows.

Here's a first pass at the first program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int pnum, quantity;
    float price;
    char num1[20];
    char num2[20];
    char num3[20];
    char str[100] = "";

    printf("This program stores a business inventory.\n");
    fp = fopen("inventory.txt", "w");

    do
    {
        printf("Please enter item data (part number, quantity, price): ");
        if (scanf("%d, %d, %f", &pnum, &quantity, &price) != 3)
        {
            pnum = 0;
            quantity = 0;
            price = 0.0;
        }

        sprintf(num1, "%d", pnum);
        sprintf(num2, "%d", quantity);
        sprintf(num3, "%.1f", price);

        strcat(str, num1);
        strcat(str, " ");
        if (pnum != 0)
        {
            strcat(str, num2);
            strcat(str, " ");
            strcat(str, num3);
            strcat(str, " ");
        }
        else
        {
            strcat(str, num1);
            strcat(str, " ");
            strcat(str, num1);
            strcat(str, " ");
            strcat(str, num1);
            strcat(str, " ");
        }
    } while (pnum != 0 && strlen(str) < sizeof(str) - 20);

    fwrite(str, 1, sizeof(str) + 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Thank you. Inventory stored in file inventory.txt.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Given input file:

```
123, 45, 56.78
234, 56, 67.89
333, 77, 88.88
0, 234, 100.92
```

it produces the output file:

```
0x0000: 31 32 33 20 34 35 20 35 36 2E 38 20 32 33 34 20   123 45 56.8 234 
0x0010: 35 36 20 36 37 2E 39 20 33 33 33 20 37 37 20 38   56 67.9 333 77 8
0x0020: 38 2E 39 20 30 20 30 20 30 20 30 20 00 00 00 00   8.9 0 0 0 0 ....
0x0030: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
* (2)
0x0060: 00 00 00 00 01                                    .....
0x0065:
```

Note all the trailing null bytes.

A second pass simplifies the code by using `snprintf()` to format the line and then writes that with `fwrite()` — though it is very tempting to use just `fprintf()` to format and write.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char filename[] = "inventory.txt";
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for writing\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("This program stores a business inventory.\n");

    int pnum, quantity;
    float price;
    do
    {
        printf("Please enter item data (part number, quantity, price): ");
        if (scanf("%d, %d, %f", &pnum, &quantity, &price) != 3 || pnum == 0)
        {
            pnum = 0;
            quantity = 0;
            price = 0.0;
        }
        char str[100];
        snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%d %d %.2f\n", pnum, quantity, price);
        if (fwrite(str, sizeof(char), strlen(str), fp) != strlen(str))
            break;
    } while (pnum != 0);

    fclose(fp);
    printf("Thank you. Inventory stored in file %s\n", filename);

    return 0;
}
```

For the same input data, it produces the output:

```
0x0000: 31 32 33 20 34 35 20 35 36 2E 37 38 0A 32 33 34   123 45 56.78.234
0x0010: 20 35 36 20 36 37 2E 38 39 0A 33 33 33 20 37 37    56 67.89.333 77
0x0020: 20 38 38 2E 38 38 0A 30 20 30 20 30 2E 30 30 0A    88.88.0 0 0.00.
0x0030:
```

Or, as normal text:

```
123 45 56.78
234 56 67.89
333 77 88.88
0 0 0.00
```

Note there are no null bytes in the file at all.

A mildly revised reader program looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int pnum, quantity;
    float price;

    printf("Below are the items in your inventory\n");

    printf("Part# Quantity Item Price\n");

    fp = fopen("inventory.txt", "r");
    //rewind(fp);
    do
    {
        if (fscanf(fp, "%d %d %f", &pnum, &quantity, &price) != 3)
            break;

        printf("%5d", pnum);
        printf("%9d", quantity);
        printf("       $%.1f\n", price);
    } while (pnum != 0);

    printf("All data read\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Given the outputs from the previous programs, it produces the same report from both versions of the data file:

```
Below are the items in your inventory
Part# Quantity Item Price
  123       45       $56.8
  234       56       $67.9
  333       77       $88.9
    0        0       $0.0
All data read
```

You could revise the second program to print all the data for each line of output in a single call to `printf()`.